# Combine multiple rows into Single row using particular column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I need to combine both records into single record. I have a **Billable** column value as '**Yes**' and '**No**'

If Value is '**Yes**' then it will sum row-wise and created new columns as '**Billable**'

**Billing = df[Billing] * sum/168 * 100**

If value is '**No**' then it will be sum row-wise and created new column as '**Non-Billable**'.

**Non-Billing = df[Non-Billing] * sum/ 168 * 100**

Data:

```
|Employee Name  |    Java  |  Python  | .Net  |  React |  Billable|                                  
|Priya          |    10    |          |   5   |        |  Yes     |                     
|Priya          |          |  10      |       |     5  |  No      |  
|Krithi         |          |   10     |   20  |        |  No      |
```

**Output**

Priya is in both billable and non-billable, priya name appears in two rows. I need to merge in single row with Employee Name. So expected output should be

```
| Employee Name |   Java    | Python    |.Net   | React | Total       |Billing      | Non-Billing|     
| Priya         |   10      | 10        | 5     | 5     | 30          |8.928571429  | 8.928571429|     
| Krithi        |   10      | 20        |       |       | 30          |             | 17.85714286|
```

Expected Output billable and non-billable data should be in single row.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSnU2.png)

But I am getting output in two rows Billable and Non-Billable

[Current Output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3mpq.png)

```
total=df.sum(axis=1)
df.insert(len(df.columns),column='Total',value=total)

x = (Billable_cal.loc[:,:].sum(axis=1)/available*100).round(2)
df["Billing"] = np.where(df["Billable"] == "Yes", x, "")
df["Non Billing"] = np.where(df["Billable"] == "No", x, "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First aggregate by `Employee Name` names to `df1`, then aggregate by `Billable` with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), for `sum` per both columns, sum by all columns, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), divide and multiple and last add to `df1` for final ouput:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Employee Name', sort=False).sum(min_count=1)

df['Billable'] = np.where(df['Billable'] == 'Yes', 'Billing','Non-Billing')

df2 = (df.groupby(['Employee Name','Billable'])
        .sum()
        .sum(axis=1)
        .unstack()
        .div(168)
        .mul(100))

df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
print (df)
  Employee Name  Java  Python  .Net  React   Billing  Non-Billing
0         Priya  10.0    10.0   5.0    5.0  8.928571     8.928571
1        Krithi   NaN    10.0  20.0    NaN       NaN    17.857143
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help jezrael, I have Utilization column as 168. If employee have both billable and non-billable then Utilization column tries to sum the value as 336.  I don't need the sum value for Utilization column. How to do that?

Comment: 'df2 = (df.groupby(['Employee Name','Billable'])['Java','Python','.Net','React'].sum().sum(axis=1).unstack().div(168).mul(100)).round(2)'

Comment: @Gomathi do you think Total column? Not sure if understand.

Comment: No, There is a another column name as "Utilization" value as 168 for entire column. If employee have both Billable and Non-Billable value it calculate (168+168 = 336), but i need only 168 for this column. 
**Output**:

| Employee Name | Java | Python | .Net     | React    | Total   | Utilization 
| Priya                 | 10         | 10          | 5             | 5    | 30   | 336      |Amount |Billing         |Non-Billing
|17.85% |8.928571429 |8.928571429

Comment: @Gomathi - This column is in input data? And all values in column are same - 168?

Comment: Yes, It's part of input data, even given particular column also it calculate the sum value 

code:
df2 = (df.groupby(['Employee Name','Billable'])[list_column].sum().sum(axis=1).unstack().div(168).mul(100)).round(2)

Comment: Getting Output:
Employee Name Java Python .Net    React Total Utilization 
Priya                 10         10          5    5          30          336                 

Amount Billing             Non-Billing 
17.85% 8.928571429     8.928571429


Expected Output:
Employee Name Java Python .Net     React    Total Utilization 
Priya                10         10          5      5             30    168         
Amount               Billing                Non-Billing 
17.85%               8.928571429        8.928571429

Comment: @Gomathi - So this column is not shown in input data in question? And has same values `168` ?

Comment: The Utilization column is a calculated column, its not available in input data.... Its a 168 constant value for Utilization column

Comment: @Gomathi - Is possible see your complete solution, mainly where is count `Utilization` column?

Comment: I need to modify available column values inn billable and non-billable utilization how to do